# Realizing a vector bundle as a summand of a trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

A very interesting statement, in my opinion, that is proved in the famous Serre-Swan paper is the following lemma

**Lemma**: Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $\xi \rightarrow X$ a vector bundle . Then there exists a trivial vector bundle $\eta$, i.e. $\eta=X\times \mathbb{R}^n$ for some n, and a vector bundle epimorphism  $\eta \rightarrow \xi$  over the identity map.

It is an immediate corrolary that any vector bundle over a compact topological space can be completed to a trivial vector bundle, in the sense that it is a direct summand of a trivial vector bundle over X.

It seems to me that the compactness assumption is critical in the proof of this Lemma, however, I was wondering if the statement is also true for vector bundles over arbirtary smooth manifolds.

Comment: Your title should be *Stably trivializing ...* (without quotes).

Comment: @TedShifrin OK thanks, I edited. Is there a reason for this characterization?

Comment: I think a vector bundle is stably trivial if it admits a direct summand such that the sum is a trivial vector bundle, so pretty much by definition. Mind you, this comes from a very deep and interesting mathematical  framework which should be related to K theory and of which I know nothing about.

Comment: See Theorem 3.3 in Chapter 4 of Hirsch's *Differential Topology*. This gives exactly your result. "Stably" comes from the notion, as GFR suggests, that a bundle should be "equivalent" to its direct sum with any number of trivial line bundles. So, actually, my comment is not quite right. Being a summand of a trivial bundle does not say that the other summand is itself trivial. I spoke too quickly.

Comment: @GFR I was not aware of this definition, thanks! Ι will look up the book recommended in another comment for more details.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. So any vector bundle admits a direct summand such that their direct sum is isomorphic to a trivial bundle... This is very interesting in my opinion.

Comment: Well, as motivation, you can think of this: Any manifold admits an embedding into $\Bbb R^N$. That means that its tangent bundle will be a direct sum of the trivial $N$-plane bundle (the other summand being the normal bundle). This is just a slight generalization of that result.

Comment: I propose changing the title, since you aren't asking if every bundle is stably trivial but instead if every bundle is a summand of a trivial bundle.

Comment: @JamesCameron You are right, now the title describes more accurately the nature of my question. However I am a bit confused. Saying that a bundle is stably trivial and being a summand of a trivial bundle are two different things?

Comment: Yes, you are stably trivial if you are a summand of a trivial bundle AND the complement is trivial. However, it might be the case that you are a summand of a trivial bundle but the complement is not trivial. For example, if you look at the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$ it is a summand of the trivial 2-plane bundle, but the complement is another copy of the tautological line bundle.

Comment: Compare this with the tangent bundle of $S^2$, if you sum with a trivial line bundle you get the trivial 3-plane bundle, so the tangent bundle is stably trivial.

Answer (score 3):

This is true. In fact, any vector bundle over something homotopy equivalent to a finite dimensional CW complex (for example, over a non compact manifold) is a summand of a trivial bundle.

To see this, note that you just need to prove it for tautological bundle of a Grassmannian, since every vector bundle over such a space is pulled back from the tautological bundle over a Grassmannian. The tautological $k$-plane bundle $E_k \to \mathrm{Gr}_{k} \mathbb{R^n}$ is a summand of the trivial $n$-plane bundle over $Gr_{k} \mathbb{R}^n$, which finishes the proof.

By the way, its not true that vector bundles over *any* space have a complement, consider the universal line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$. Since $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}, \mathbb{F}_2 )$ is a polynomial ring with generator the first Stieffel-Whitney class of the universal bundle, this bundle doesn't have a complement.

Comment: You claim that every rank $k$ vector bundle over a space homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex admits a classifying map to $\operatorname{Gr}_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, as opposed to the classifying space $\operatorname{Gr}_k(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$. Why is that true?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It's since a map from a finite dimensional CW complex into $Gr_{k}\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ must be homotopic to a map landing in a finite dimensional subcomplex, which is contained in a $Gr_{k} \mathbb{R}^n$ (thinking of $BO(k)$ as the colimit of the finite dimensional Grassmannians)

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but why is a finite-dimensional subcomplex of $\operatorname{Gr}_k(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ contained in $\operatorname{Gr}_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $n$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The point is that there is a cell structure so that the map $G_{k}  \mathbb{R}^{n} \to Gr_{k}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is an isomorphism on the $r$ skeleton for $r$ small enough, I think $r< n-k$ is enough (I believe this is in Milnor-Stasheff). So, for every $l$ the $l$ skeleton of $Gr_{k}\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is contained in $Gr_{k}\mathbb{R}^N$ for $N$ big enough.